# How to see code in right panel of xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

This is a very beginner issue that I am stuck with.

I need to connect some storyboard elements to elements in the corresponding .h files.

But I can't seem to get the .h file code to show up when I click on a storyboard element.

Here is what I see:

[image]

Any idea how to make the code chow up when I click on elements in the storyboard? I am using `xCode 7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcut: Alt + Cmd + Return

GUI element: Is the two overlapping circles in the top right of the screen

Menu: View > Assistant Editor > Show Assistant Editor